# Is endomorphisms of a Poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ Group is a $n \times n$ matrix?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Given an $n$-step poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group

$$H_n = (\dots((\mathbb{Z} \rtimes_{\bar{\phi_1}} \mathbb{Z})\rtimes_{\bar{\phi_2}} \mathbb{Z}) \rtimes_{\bar{\phi_3}} \mathbb{Z} \dots ) \rtimes_{\phi_{n-1}} \mathbb{Z}$$

with the star operation $\star$ as the semi-direct products of two groups depending on the group homomorphism $\bar{\phi}_i$. Then we take $e_i$ to be a vector of length $n$ where the $i$th entry is $1$ and else $0$. Thus $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is the polycyclic generating sequence of $H_n$.
Furthermore, since a poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group is a polycyclic group, hence for every $x \in H_n$, $\mathfrak{f} \in E(H_n)$ ($E(G)$ is the notation for endomorphism of $G$), it follows

$$
\mathfrak{f}(x) = \mathfrak{f}(e_1^{x_1} \star \dots \star e_n^{x_n}) = \mathfrak{f}(e_1)^{x_1} \star \dots \star \mathfrak{f}(e_n)^{x_n}.$$

Thus $\mathfrak{f}$ is entirely determined by $\mathfrak{f}(e_i)$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$. In other words $\mathfrak{f}$ can be represented as a $n \times n$ matrix.

**Question**: What concludes that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(H_n)$ can be represented as a $n \times n$ matrix? An injective homomorphism to $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ would be great since I only focuses on groups.

I'm asking this because if $G$ is an $n$-step poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group then $\mathfrak{f} \in E(G)$ can be represented as a $n \times n$ matrix.

Furthermore, I want to make sure that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z})$ for a specific $\phi \in Aut(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1})$ can be represented as an $n \times n$ matrix. I've also proved that $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-3} \times H$ where $H$ is the Heisenberg group. Probably someone can help me prove that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-3} \times H)$ can be represented as an $n \times n$ matrix. If that's proven then $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z})$ can be represented as an $n \times n$ matrix.

**Alternative Question**: Please help me prove that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-3} \times H)$ can be represented as a $n \times n$ matrix? By groups analogy is recommended since I'm only working on groups.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an injective homomorphism from $E(H_n)$ to $n\times n$ matrices over $Z$? Over a field? What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: An injective homomorphism from $E(H_n)$ to $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ would be really great. I've tried expanding the last equation I wrote but I got really confused in the middle.

Comment: What do you know? The corresponding statement for automorphism groups, which is less general than what you want, is a theorem of Marzljakov. See Theorem 5.6 of Dan Segal's book, p.96. I don't think the proof gets that the automorphism is represented as easily as you write. In particular, I don't think the degree of the matrices can necessarily be taken to be the Hirsch length. (However, I'm not an expert on this.)

Comment: I see, may I know the title of the book you're referring to? So I actually want to proof that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z})$ for a specific $\phi \in Aut(\mathbb{Z}^{n-1})$ can be represented as an $n \times n$ matrix. Turns out, I've proved that $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{n-3} \times H$ where $H$ is the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{Z}$. Probably it is easier to prove that $\mathfrak{f} \in E(\mathbb{Z}^{n-3} \times H)$ can be represented as $n \times n$ matrix? However, I haven't figure how to prove that. Thanks.

Comment: The book is called 'Polycyclic Groups'.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you. Probably my alternative question that I've posted (edited) is way simpler? Thanks for the help once again!